# ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (179) Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I am using Pandas.

I have a dataset where I scraped linkedin for a company's employee data.

I am trying to slice a list in one column and make a new column with the slice but get this error.

This is what I tried.

1. I filled in every nan with the word "blank"
   2)I split the column into a list on spaces.

```
employees = employees.fillna("blank")

employees["jobDateRange"] = employees["jobDateRange"].str.split(" ")
```

The Result:

`[Aug, 2013, –, Present]`

Then I tried:

`employees["job1month"] = employees["jobDateRange"][0]`

And I get:

ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (179)

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong and what this error means? (Hopefully in plain English. I can't understand any of the other StackOverflow answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but to access an item in a list within a pandas series, you must also use `str`. Therefore, you should replace:

```
employees["job1month"] = employees["jobDateRange"][0]
```

With:

```
employees["job1month"] = employees["jobDateRange"].str[0]
```